# Android: Multiple simultaneous count-down timers in a ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, countdown

I am creating an app that requires a ListView with an undetermined number of elements, each of which has a timer that counts down from a variable number. I am able to successfully make **one** of them count down, but I can't figure out how to include a timer in each element of the ListView.

I am currently using a [CountDownTimer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html) (make sure to capitalize the D if copying from the website, they have it wrong).

Any code or sources to point me in the right direction are much appreciated.

Here is my current EventAdapter class, it sets the text displayed in each ListView element's TextView. What I need to do is make the TextView count down every second. Since each element of the ListView is displaying something different, I suppose I need a way of differentiating each element.

I could just update the whole list every second, but there are other elements I have not included such as images loaded from the internet that it would be impractical to refresh every second.

```
private class EventAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Event>
{
    private ArrayList<Event> items;

    public EventAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Event> items) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
        }

        Event e = items.get(position);

        if (e != null) {
            TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text);

            if (tv != null)
                tv.setText(e.getName());
        }
        return v;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give us more of a code sample from what you have written so far? Without knowing what you have written, it's very hard to guess what is wrong.

Comment: It's not so much something wrong, I just don't know how to begin to implement it. But I will post some code in just a sec

Comment: I actually have the same issue and going to use singleton CountDownTimer which run myClickMethod() method from rxJava, where each view is subscribed that event and get notofication to update its state. I'm just considering this as some sort of solution.

Comment: Please have a look on this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/40236877/5644410

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please have a look [here at my blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20120806161550/http://www.rochdev.com/2011/06/counters-in-listview.html) where you will find an example on how to achieve this.

One solution is to put the TextView that represents each counter into a HashMap together with it's position in the list as the key.

In getView()

```
TextView counter = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.myTextViewTwo);
if (counter != null) {
    counter.setText(myData.getCountAsString());
    // add the TextView for the counter to the HashMap.
    mCounterList.put(position, counter);
}
```

Then you can update the counters by using a Handler and where you post a runnable.

```
private final Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        MyData myData;
        TextView textView;

        // if counters are active
        if (mCountersActive) {                
            if (mCounterList != null && mDataList != null) {
                for (int i=0; i < mDataList.size(); i++) {
                    myData = mDataList.get(i);
                    textView = mCounterList.get(i);
                    if (textView != null) {
                        if (myData.getCount() >= 0) {
                            textView.setText(myData.getCountAsString());
                            myData.reduceCount();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            // update every second
            mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: [Please provide context for links](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer). Include at least the main points directly in your answer, preferably including a code sample. It's ok to refer to your blog for more details, but your answer should make sense even if the reader chooses not to follow the link.

Answer (score 11):

This is an example of the way I do it and it works perfect:

```
public class TestCounterActivity extends ListActivity
{
    TestAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Example values
        ArrayList<Date> values = new ArrayList<Date>();
        values.add(new Date(1482464366239L));
        values.add(new Date(1480464366239L));
        values.add(new Date(1470464366239L));
        values.add(new Date(1460464366239L));
        values.add(new Date(1450464366239L));
        values.add(new Date(1440464366239L));
        values.add(new Date(1430464366239L));
        values.add(new Date(1420464366239L));
        values.add(new Date(1410464366239L));
        values.add(new Date(1490464366239L));

        adapter = new TestAdapter(this, values);

        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop()
    {
        super.onStop();

        // Dont forget to cancel the running timers
        adapter.cancelAllTimers();
    }
}
```

And this is the adapter

```
public class TestAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Date> 
{
    private final Activity context;
    private final List<Date> values;
    private HashMap<TextView,CountDownTimer> counters;

    static class TestViewHolder 
    {
        public TextView tvCounter;
    }

    public TestAdapter(Activity context, List<Date> values) 
    {
        super(context, R.layout.test_row, values);
        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;
        this.counters = new HashMap<TextView, CountDownTimer>();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        View rowView = convertView;

        if(rowView == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test_row, null);
            final TestViewHolder viewHolder = new TestViewHolder();
            viewHolder.tvCounter = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvCounter);

            rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }

        TestViewHolder holder = (TestViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
        final TextView tv = holder.tvCounter;

        CountDownTimer cdt = counters.get(holder.tvCounter);
        if(cdt!=null)
        {
            cdt.cancel();
            cdt=null;
        }

        Date date = values.get(position);
        long currentDate = Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getTime();
        long limitDate = date.getTime();
        long difference = limitDate - currentDate;

        cdt = new CountDownTimer(difference, 1000)
        {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) 
            {
                int days = 0;
                int hours = 0;
                int minutes = 0;
                int seconds = 0;
                String sDate = "";

                if(millisUntilFinished > DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS)
                {
                    days = (int) (millisUntilFinished / DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS);
                    sDate += days+"d";
                }

                millisUntilFinished -= (days*DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS);

                if(millisUntilFinished > DateUtils.HOUR_IN_MILLIS)
                {
                    hours = (int) (millisUntilFinished / DateUtils.HOUR_IN_MILLIS);
                }

                millisUntilFinished -= (hours*DateUtils.HOUR_IN_MILLIS);

                if(millisUntilFinished > DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS)
                {
                    minutes = (int) (millisUntilFinished / DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS);
                }

                millisUntilFinished -= (minutes*DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS);

                if(millisUntilFinished > DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS)
                {
                    seconds = (int) (millisUntilFinished / DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS);
                }

                sDate += " "+String.format("%02d",hours)+":"+String.format("%02d",minutes)+":"+String.format("%02d",seconds);
                tv.setText(sDate.trim());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                tv.setText("Finished");
            }
        };

        counters.put(tv, cdt);
        cdt.start();

        return rowView;
    }

    public void cancelAllTimers()
    {
        Set<Entry<TextView, CountDownTimer>> s = counters.entrySet();
        Iterator it = s.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext())
        {
            try
            {
                Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry)it.next();
                CountDownTimer cdt = (CountDownTimer)pairs.getValue();

                cdt.cancel();
                cdt = null;
            }
            catch(Exception e){}
        }

        it=null;
        s=null;
        counters.clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you , its simple and awesome solution , saved my time.

Answer (score 4):

after checking few ways to do that this is a creative solution i wrote  .its simple and works perfectly  .

the idea it to check if the `Runnable` that updates the data is updating the same `TextView` and if the `TextView` is related to different view the `Runnable`will stop and by this way there will be no extra `Thread`'s in the background so there will be no blinking text's or memory leak.

1 . inside your `getView()` add each TextView tag with his position .

```
text = (TextView) view
        .findViewById(R.id.dimrix);
text.setTag(position);
```

2 . create class that implements Runnable so we can pass parameters .

```
public class mUpdateClockTask implements Runnable {
    private TextView tv;
    final Handler mClockHandler = new Handler();
    String tag;

    public mUpdateClockTask(TextView tv,
            String tag) {
        this.tv = tv;
        this.tag = tag;
    }

    public void run() {

        if (tv.getTag().toString().equals(tag)) {
                        // do what ever you want to happen every second
            mClockHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }

    }

};
```

so what happen here is unless the `TextView` is not equals to the original tag the `Runnable` will stop .

3 . go back to your `getView()`

```
        final Handler mClockHandler = new Handler();
        mUpdateClockTask clockTask = new mUpdateClockTask(text,
                activeDraw, text.getTag().toString());
        mClockHandler.post(clockTask);
```

that's it , work's perfect !

Comment: Thanks, this is a very old question and I'm no longer working on this project but maybe your answer will help someone else.

Comment: thats is the idea , i"m sure you figure this out by now (-:

Comment: this is the answer

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution of using ListView with multiple CountDownTimer. Firstly, we create a class **MyCustomTimer** that holds the CountDownTimer:

```
public class MyCustomTimer{
    public MyCustomTimer() {
    }
    public void setTimer(TextView tv, long time) {
        new CountDownTimer(time, 1000) {
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                //Set formatted date to your TextView
                tv.setText(millisUntilFinished);
            }
            public void onFinish() {
                tv.setText("Done!");
            }
        }.start();
    }
}
```

Then, initilize the created class in your adapter:

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private MyCustomTimer myTimer;
    private ArrayList<Item> myItems;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Item> data) {
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        myTimer= new MyCustomTimer();
        myItems = data;
    }

    //... implementation of other methods

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_row, null);
        TextView tvTimer = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textview_timer);
        TextView tvName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textview_name);

        Item item = data.get(position);

        tvName.setText(item.getName());
        myTimer.setTimer(tvTimer, item.getTime());

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: of course it wont work . its create new CountDownTimer for each view without checking if its new view or existing one . after one scroll you will have more than one CountDownTimer on each view .