# Android: Create a timer in Recycleview row

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, countdowntimer

I want to create recycle view with a counter in each row. Each row has a separate timer. This time should run separately. I able to create a timer but each time app gets restarted, the timer is getting reset.

Thank you in advance for your help!!

[image]

Comment: "each time app gets restarted"? What are you trying to do ? Do you want the time will also run when app is not open and resume with current updated value ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32257586/how-to-handle-multiple-countdown-timers-in-recyclerview

Comment: check with -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35860780/recyclerview-with-multiple-countdown-timers-causes-flickering

Comment: @ADM: Yes. I want to run counter even app is closed. It should resume to it's value when app is reopened.

Comment: Run the counter on server and get the time at start of app . Thats the only solution i think .

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
public CountDownTimer timer;
```

in onBindViewHolder(...)

```
 if (holder.timer != null) {
     holder.timer.cancel();
 }

 holder.timer = new CountDownTimer(timeEnd - System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000) {
     @Override
     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
       // update text..        
     }

     @Override
     public void onFinish() {
       // update text..
     }
    };
```

that worked for me!!!

Comment: I tried this solution, But when I restart my application. The timer is getting reset.