# RecyclerView Adapter is laggy because of onBindViewHolder()

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I have an app with a `RecyclerView` and an customized `Adapter` which gets that from a parse backend.

My adapter contains a few `TextView`s, a `Button`, a small `ImageView`. Some of my `TextView`s require a function (calculating upvote count and stuff like this) in my `Adapter`'s `onBindViewHolder()` to get their data.

I've noticed that my scrolling is really slow and laggy because of the functions that are called in `onBindViewHolder()`.

Where should I set my data and call my functions in order to get a smooth scrolling ?

EDIT 1:

Here's my Adapter Code:

```
public class PostAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PostAdapter.ViewHolder> {
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView     postName;
    public ImageView    postCatIcon;

    public TextView     postDays;
    public TextView     postDaysLabel;
    public TextView     postHours;
    public TextView     postHoursLabel;
    public TextView     postMinutes;
    public TextView     postMinutesLabel;
    public TextView     postDistance;

    public TextView     postLikes;
    public TextView     postAuthor;
    public LikeButton   likepost;

    private Post post;


    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        postName    = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_name);
        postCatIcon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_cat_icon);

        postDays            = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_days);
        postDaysLabel       = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_days_label);
        postHours           = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_hours);
        postHoursLabel      = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_hours_label);
        postMinutes         = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_minutes);
        postMinutesLabel    = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_minutes_label);
        postDistance        = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_distance);

        likePost    = (LikeButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.like_the_post);
        postAuthor  = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_author);
        postLikes   = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_likes);
    }

    public void setData(Post post){
        this.post = post;
        updateTimeRemaining(System.currentTimeMillis());
    }

    public void updateTimeRemaining(long currentTime) {
        long diff = post.getDate().getTime() - currentTime;

        int minutes = (int) ((diff / (1000*60)) % 60);
        int hours   = (int) ((diff / (1000*60*60)) % 24);
        int days = (int) (diff / (1000*60*60*24));


        String strgMinutes = "00";
        String strgHours = "00";
        String strgDays = "00";

        if(minutes < 10)
            strgMinutes = "0" + String.valueOf(minutes);
        else
            strgMinutes = String.valueOf(minutes);

        if(hours < 10)
            strgHours = "0" + String.valueOf(hours);
        else
            strgHours = String.valueOf(hours);

        if(days < 10){
            strgDays = "0" + String.valueOf(days);
        }else
            strgDays = String.valueOf(days);

        postDays.setText(strgDays);
        postHours.setText(strgHours);
        postMinutes.setText(strgMinutes);
    }
}

public static class ProgressViewHolder extends PostAdapter.ViewHolder {
    public ProgressBar progressBar;

    public ProgressViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    }
}

private List<Post> mPosts;
private Context mContext;
private ListFragment mFragment;

private final int VIEW_ITEM = 1;
private final int VIEW_PROG = 0;

ArrayList<PostAdapter.ViewHolder> viewHoldersList;
private Handler handler = new Handler();
private Runnable updateRemainingTimeRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        synchronized (viewHoldersList) {
            for (PostAdapter.ViewHolder holder : viewHoldersList) {
                holder.updateTimeRemaining(currentTime);
            }
        }
        handler.postDelayed(this, 60000);
    }
};

// The minimum amount of items to have below your current scroll position before loading more.
private int visibleThreshold = 2;
private int lastVisibleItem, totalItemCount;
private boolean loading;
private OnLoadMoreListener onLoadMoreListener;

public PostAdapter(List<Post> posts, Context context, ListFragment fragment, RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    mContext = context;
    mPosts = posts;
    mFragment = fragment;

    if (recyclerView.getLayoutManager() instanceof LinearLayoutManager) {

        final LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager();
        recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

                totalItemCount = linearLayoutManager.getItemCount();
                lastVisibleItem = linearLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();
                if (!loading && totalItemCount <= (lastVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
                    // End has been reached
                    // Do something
                    if (onLoadMoreListener != null) {
                        onLoadMoreListener.onLoadMore();
                    }
                    loading = true;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    viewHoldersList = new ArrayList<>();
    startUpdateTimer();
}

public PostAdapter(List<Post> posts, Context context, RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    mContext = context;
    mPosts = posts;

    if (recyclerView.getLayoutManager() instanceof LinearLayoutManager) {

        final LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager();
        recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

                totalItemCount = linearLayoutManager.getItemCount();
                lastVisibleItem = linearLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();
                if (!loading && totalItemCount <= (lastVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
                    // End has been reached
                    // Do something
                    if (onLoadMoreListener != null) {
                        onLoadMoreListener.onLoadMore();
                    }
                    loading = true;
                }
            }
        });
    }
    viewHoldersList = new ArrayList<>();
    startUpdateTimer();
}

private void startUpdateTimer() {
    handler.postDelayed(updateRemainingTimeRunnable,60000);
}

public PostAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    Context context         = parent.getContext();
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View postView;
    ViewHolder viewHolder;

    if (viewType == VIEW_ITEM) {
        postView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);

         viewHolder = new ViewHolder(postView);
    } else {
        postView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.loading_item, parent, false);

        viewHolder = new ProgressViewHolder(postView);
    }

    return viewHolder;
}

public void onBindViewHolder(final PostAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
    if (viewHolder instanceof ViewHolder) {
        final Post post = mPosts.get(position);
        if(post != null){
            synchronized (viewHoldersList) {
                viewHolder.setData(post);
                viewHoldersList.add(viewHolder);
            }

            Category cat                    = post.getCategory();
            TextView nameTextView           = viewHolder.postName;
            TextView authorTextView         = viewHolder.postAuthor;
            final TextView likesTextView    = viewHolder.postLikes;
            ImageView CatIconView           = viewHolder.postCatIcon;
            final LikeButton likeButtonView = viewHolder.likePost;
            TextView postDistance           = viewHolder.postDistance;
            ParseUser postAuthor = null;

            if(mFragment != null) {
                if (mFragment.getIfFilteredByDistance()) {
                    postDistance.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    Location postLocation = new Location("Post location");
                    if(post.getLocation() != null){
                        postLocation.setLongitude(post.getLocation().getLongitude());
                        postLocation.setLatitude(post.getLocation().getLatitude());

                        GPSTracker gpsTracker = new GPSTracker(mContext);
                        if (gpsTracker.canGetLocation()) {
                            Location myLocation = new Location("My location");
                            myLocation.setLatitude(gpsTracker.getLatitude());
                            myLocation.setLongitude(gpsTracker.getLongitude());

                            postDistance.setText((Math.round(myLocation.distanceTo(postLocation)) / 1000) + " km");
                        } else
                            gpsTracker.showSettingsAlert();
                    }
                } else
                    postDistance.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }


            try{
                postAuthor = post.getAuthor().fetchIfNeeded();
            }catch (ParseException e){
                Log.e("Parse:", e.getMessage());
            }

            saveActivitiesToLocalDatastore(post);

            final int likeCount = ((PostApplication)mContext).getPostLikeCount(post);
            likesTextView.setText(String.valueOf(likeCount));

            likeButtonView.setLiked(((PostApplication)mContext).getIfLiked(post));

            viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, DetailActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("PostID",post.getObjectId());
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    mContext.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

            likeButtonView.setOnLikeListener(new OnLikeListener() {
                @Override
                public void liked(LikeButton likeButton) {
                    if(((PostApplication)mContext).likePost(post))
                        likesTextView.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(likesTextView.getText().toString()) + 1));
                }

                @Override
                public void unLiked(LikeButton likeButton) {
                    if(((PostApplication)mContext).unlikePost(post))
                        likesTextView.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(likesTextView.getText().toString()) -1));

                }
            });


            nameTextView.setText(post.getTitle());
            authorTextView.setText(post.getAuthor().getUsername());


            CatIconView.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext,mContext.getResources().getIdentifier(cat.getIconName()+"_18dp","drawable",mContext.getPackageName())));

        }
    } else {
        ((ProgressViewHolder) viewHolder).progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
    }
}



public int getItemCount() {
    return mPosts.size();
}

private void saveActivitiesToLocalDatastore(final Post post){
    // Saves Likes to Parse local datastore
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return mposts.get(position) != null ? VIEW_ITEM : VIEW_PROG;
}


public void setLoaded() {
    loading = false;
}

public void setOnLoadMoreListener(OnLoadMoreListener onLoadMoreListener) {
    this.onLoadMoreListener = onLoadMoreListener;
}

public interface OnLoadMoreListener {
    void onLoadMore();
}
```

EDIT 2:

I followed this in order to fix my countdown's flickering:

[Recyclerview with multiple countdown timers causes flickering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35860780/recyclerview-with-multiple-countdown-timers-causes-flickering)

EDIT 3:

I tried running the app without the additionals methods like saveActivitiesInBackgroud, and the listeners and it works really smooth

Comment: Post the code please.

Comment: The answer to that depends on where you store the downloaded data. Realm? SQLite? In-memory? Shared pref (lol)?

Comment: RecyclerView is not laggy. Probably you have some mistake in your adapter code. Please send your codes, so people could help you.

Comment: Sorry, posted the code just now

Comment: You probably shouldn't  create a new GpsTracker per every single displayed element, that might help a bit. Also consider not using `synchronized`

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I used synchronized to avoid creating a new CountDownTimer on every OnBindViewHolder() which created more lags. How should I do that ?

And I tried without the GPSTracker and my saveActivitiesToLocalDatastore and the list is still not smooth

Comment: hmm, what is the size of `viewHoldersList`? are you sure its 10 or something and not some big number like 10000 or so?

Comment: @pskink viewHoldersList is 6 at the start of the app and adds one everytime a new post is visible in the list

Comment: are you sure? you call `viewHoldersList.add` each time `onBindViewHolder` is called but i dont see anywhere you delete from it? just add `Log.d` inside `onBindViewHolder` and double check it (of course you need do scroll your `RV` a bit so `onBindViewHolder` is called multiple times)

Comment: @pskink You're right, I never remove anything from it, it only get's bigger everytime I scroll, when should I remove objects from it ?

Comment: You shouldn't even add anything to it directly, you should just call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` when the timer reaches 0

Comment: @pskink I don't quite understand what you mean, but my timers are most likely not to expire while on the view, with values like 100 days so I doubt it will increase performances also, I tried running the app only with the timers and not any other TextView and It runs really smooth

Comment: yeah,  @EpicPandaForce is right: update your data model first and them call `notifyDataSetChanged` / `notifyItemChanged` / `notifyItemRangeChanged`

Comment: @Archipel your UI freezes because you synchronize between `onBindViewHolder()` and that iteration that updates the updatedTime in the holders

Comment: @pskink Okay I will try that, would you by any chance know an example where they use those methods ?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce so I shouldn't get rid of synchronize ? where should I call it then ?

Comment: You shouldn't even have `synchronized` in here, this is a RecyclerView's  Adapter

Comment: @EpicPandaForce so the link I posted under my second edit also wrong ? I'm kinda confused right now

Comment: This is a good time to start [performance profiling](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/index.html) :) (here's a [codelabs](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-perf-testing/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#0))

Comment: you don't need `synchronized` bacause all happening on UI thread.

Answer (score 2):

If u want use RecyclerView u need to use onBindViewHolder. Its not problem with OnBindViewHolder. Problem is with ur spaghetti code and also u not store the informations, so this cause ur recyclerview to lags

Comment: Could you please elaborate, like what are the big mistakes with my code and how should I store the informations ?
I'm aware I have to use onBindViewHolder I was just asking how I get lighten it.

Comment: -U call sometimes informations that can be create once(new Objects).
-U can store informations that using for further(SharedPreferences, Database
u probally can go with error OUT-OF-Memory

Try using LeakCanary and see what is leaked

Comment: I tried LeakCanary, it doesn't notify me of anything

Answer (score 1):

- Try not to change `ViewHolder` state outside of `onBindViewHolder()`. `ViewHolder` is representing view on screen but not representing data itself. `RecyclerView` tend to reuse views when they become invisible on screen and as result reuse `ViewHolder` attached to that view.
- Never store `ViewHolder` - it's `RecyclerView` responsibility to manage them.
- If you update your timer only once in `60 sec` just `notifyDataSetChanges` instead of directly update `ViewHolder`. And update view state in `onBindViewHolder` with proper time.

Comment: Okay I think I got the part about ViewHolder, but where am I supposed to call notifyDataSetChanges ?
And Should I use a CountDownTimer for my timer in this case ?

Comment: call it in `updateRemainingTimeRunnable::run` instead of looping over view holders.

Comment: Okay so i'm keeping my updateTimeRemaining() method in my viewholder and getting rid of the setData() and all the synchronized is that correct ?

I'm sorry I'm new to android developping and I'm not to familiar with those kinds of things. But thanks for your help

Comment: my opinion is to move update time logic entirely outside of adapter. This timer belong to data. So in timer code you will call something like 'adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()'. Next remove 'instanceof ViewHolder -recycleview guarant that it is correct object. Move load more outside of adapter. It's not adapter responsibility to track that.

Comment: Is there anyway I could contact you so I can show my code before I used all that synchronized and ViewHolder methods and maybe you could help me adapt my previous code with notifyDataSetChanged() ?

Comment: Post code to the github, and post the link if it possibl. Or other public resource so i could grab and check on my side

Comment: Okay, I will create a sample app and share it with you

Comment: I created an app without login and other stuff but which charges the same list. If you have some time and help me with some best practice

[GitLab Repo](https://gitlab.com/schwdim/MyApp/tree/master)