# Android RecyclerView CountDownTimer Problem After Delete And Insert New Item

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have Rcylerview with Adapter each Item need 60 seconds After 60 seconds Item Remove From List :
This is My Adapter Code :

```
public class LafzAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>  {

private Activity activity;
public List<Lafz> Events;
public Typeface tempfont,tempfont2;
private  MyClickListener myClickListener;
private final List<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> lstHolders=new ArrayList<>();

private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
private Runnable updateRemainingTimeRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized (lstHolders) {
            for (RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder : lstHolders) {
                ((UserViewHolder) holder).updateTimeRemaining();
            }
        }
    }
};

public LafzAdapter(List<Lafz> Events, Activity activity, Typeface ttemp) {
    this.Events = Events;
    this.activity = activity;
    this.tempfont = ttemp;
}

public LafzAdapter(final List<Lafz> Events, Activity activity, Typeface ttemp, Typeface ttemp2) {
    this.Events = Events;
    this.activity = activity;
    this.tempfont = ttemp;
    this.tempfont2=ttemp2;
    //lstHolders = new ArrayList<>();
    startUpdateTimer();
}

@Override
protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
    super.finalize();
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(updateRemainingTimeRunnable);
}


private void startUpdateTimer() {
    Timer tmr = new Timer();
    tmr.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mHandler.post(updateRemainingTimeRunnable);
        }
    }, 1000, 1000);
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.adapterlayoutlafz, parent, false);
    UserViewHolder dataObjectHolder = new UserViewHolder(view);
    return dataObjectHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    ((UserViewHolder) holder).setdata(Events.get(position));

        synchronized (lstHolders) {
            lstHolders.add(holder);
        }
        ((UserViewHolder) holder).updateTimeRemaining();
}


 class UserViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
        implements View
        .OnClickListener{
    Lafz lafztemp;
    public TextView titlelafz;
    public TextView timerlafz;

    public TextView idnumber;
    public TextView idtype;
    public TextView iduser;



    public LinearLayout llcolor,llcolor2;

    CountDownTimer timer;
    CircularProgressBar circularProgressBar;



    public UserViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);

        titlelafz=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.titlelafz);
        titlelafz.setTypeface(tempfont2);

        timerlafz=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.timerlafz);
        timerlafz.setTypeface(tempfont);


        idnumber=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.idnumber);
        idtype=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.idtype);
        iduser=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.iduser);

        circularProgressBar=(CircularProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.circularProgressBar);




        llcolor = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.llcolor);
        llcolor2 = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.llcolor2);


        view.setOnClickListener(this);



    }

    public void setdata(Lafz l)
    {
        lafztemp = l;
        if(lafztemp.typelafz==0)
        {
            this.idnumber.setText(String.valueOf(lafztemp.id));
            this.idtype.setText(String.valueOf(lafztemp.typelafz));
            this.iduser.setText(String.valueOf(lafztemp.iduser));
            this.titlelafz.setText(lafztemp.geram+" "+"گرم"+" "+String.format("%,d",lafztemp.mazane)+" "+"تومان");
            this.timerlafz.setText(String.valueOf(lafztemp.getTimer()/1000));
            this.llcolor2.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(activity,R.color.frooshred));
        }
        // خرید
        else {
            this.idnumber.setText(String.valueOf(lafztemp.id));
            this.idtype.setText(String.valueOf(lafztemp.typelafz));
            this.iduser.setText(String.valueOf(lafztemp.iduser));
            this.titlelafz.setText(lafztemp.geram+" "+"گرم"+" "+String.format("%,d", lafztemp.mazane)+" "+"تومان");
            this.timerlafz.setText(String.valueOf(lafztemp.getTimer()/1000));
            this.llcolor2.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(activity,R.color.kharidgreen));
        }
    }


     public void updateTimeRemaining() {

         lafztemp.timer-=1000;
         this.timerlafz.setText(String.valueOf((lafztemp.getTimer()/1000)));
         Iterator<Lafz> dataIterator = Events.iterator();
         int y=0;
         if(lafztemp.timer==0)
         {
             while (dataIterator.hasNext()) {
                 Lafz rd = dataIterator.next();
                 if (rd.equals(lafztemp)) {
                     lafztemp.timer=60000;

                     this.circularProgressBar.setProgress(60f);
                     dataIterator.remove();
                     notifyItemRemoved(y);
                     notifyDataSetChanged();
                     break;
                 }
                 y++;
             }
         }
         this.circularProgressBar.setProgress(this.circularProgressBar.getProgress()-1f);
     }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        myClickListener.onItemClick(getAdapterPosition(), v);
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return Events == null ? 0 : Events.size();
}

public void setOnItemClickListener(MyClickListener myClickListener) {
    this.myClickListener = myClickListener;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}


public interface MyClickListener {
    public void onItemClick(int position, View v);
}}
```

but When Old Item Removed From List And New Item Is Added New Item It drops by two seconds per second
Clear Screen Shot : Please See These screen shot for Understand
First Image Gif: For the First Time Item Adedd Is Ok :

[image: First Time Item Added]

But After Four Item Expire And Remove From List : Four First item Item It drops by two seconds per second and after Four First Item Removed All Other Item Timer Is flicking Please See Second Gif :
[image: After Old Item Delete And New Item Added]

Comment: I used this way in this link :      https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35860780/recyclerview-with-multiple-countdown-timers-causes-flickering                  but have problem and report to above link but anyone do not help me .

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented same functionality in one of my recent projects, i have store `CountDownTimer`value inside `SparseArray`and calcel all timer on activity `onDestroy` method as well as cancel single timer on button click on item of recyclerview. please check below code :

```
class DatingRoundAdapter(
var context: Context,
var arrayList: ArrayList<TempDatingModels>,
var clickListener: DatingListClickListener) :
RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

val USER_TYPE = 1
val WATING_TYPE = 2
private var countDownMap: SparseArray<CountDownTimer>? = null

init {
    countDownMap = SparseArray()
}

public fun cancelAllTimers() {
    if (countDownMap == null) {
        return
    }
    Log.e("TAG", "size :  " + countDownMap!!.size())
    var i = 0
    val length = countDownMap!!.size()
    while (i < length) {
        val cdt = countDownMap!!.get(countDownMap!!.keyAt(i))
        cdt?.cancel()
        i++
    }
}

private fun millToMins(milliSec: Long): String {
    return CommonMethods.displayTickTimerString(milliSec)
}

fun setData(arrayList: ArrayList<TempDatingModels>) {
    this.arrayList.clear()
    this.arrayList.addAll(arrayList)
    notifyDataSetChanged()
    //setTimer()
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    var vh: RecyclerView.ViewHolder? = null
    var v: View? = null
    if (viewType == WATING_TYPE) {
        v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.item_dating_user_waiting, parent, false)
        vh = WaitingHolder(v)
    } else {
        v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.item_dating_user_dating, parent, false)
        vh = UserHolder(v)
    }
    return vh
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return arrayList.size
}

override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
    if (arrayList.get(position).type == 1)
        return USER_TYPE
    else
        return WATING_TYPE
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    if (holder.itemViewType == WATING_TYPE) {

    } else {

        if ((holder as UserHolder) != null)
            (holder as UserHolder).timer?.cancel()

        if (arrayList.get(position).status == 0) {
            setNoButton((holder as UserHolder).itemView.btnYes)
            setNoButton((holder as UserHolder).itemView.btnNo)
        } else if (arrayList.get(position).status == 1) {
            setYesButton((holder as UserHolder).itemView.btnYes)
            setNoButton((holder as UserHolder).itemView.btnNo)
        } else {
            setYesButton((holder as UserHolder).itemView.btnNo)
            setNoButton((holder as UserHolder).itemView.btnYes)
        }

        if (arrayList.get(position).isCompleted == 1) {
            (holder as UserHolder).itemView.txtTimer.text = ""
            (holder as UserHolder).timer?.cancel()
        } else {
            var rtime = arrayList.get(position).endTime - (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000)

            if (arrayList.get(position).endTime > (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000)) {
                (holder as UserHolder).timer =
                    object : CountDownTimer(rtime * 1000, Constant.CountDownInterval) {
                        override fun onFinish() {
                            if ((holder as UserHolder).timer != null) {
                                (holder as UserHolder).timer!!.cancel()
                                (holder as UserHolder).timer = null
                            }
                            arrayList.get(position).isCompleted = 1
                            arrayList.get(position).status = 1;

                            (context as LatestDatingRoundsActivity).runOnUiThread {
                                notifyDataSetChanged()
                            }
                        }

                        override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
                            (holder as UserHolder).itemView.txtTimer.text =
                                millToMins(millisUntilFinished)
                        }
                    }.start()

                Log.e(
                    "key : ",
                    (holder as UserHolder).itemView.txtTimer.hashCode().toString() + " nn "
                )

                countDownMap!!.put(
                    (holder as UserHolder).itemView.txtTimer.hashCode(),
                    (holder as UserHolder).timer
                );
            }
        }


        (holder as UserHolder).itemView.btnYes.setOnClickListener({
            clickListener.itemClickListener(position, arrayList.get(position), 1)
        })

        (holder as UserHolder).itemView.btnNo.setOnClickListener({

            for (i in 0 until countDownMap!!.size()) {
                val key = countDownMap!!.keyAt(i)

                if (key.equals((holder as UserHolder).itemView.txtTimer.hashCode())) {
                    val cdt = countDownMap!!.get(key)
                    cdt!!.cancel()
                }
            }
            //clickListener.itemClickListener(position, arrayList.get(position), 2)
        })
    }
}

private fun setYesButton(btnYes: Button) {
    btnYes.background = context.resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.button_dialog_gredient)
    btnYes.setTextColor(context.resources.getColor(R.color.white))
}

private fun setNoButton(btnYes: Button) {
    btnYes.background = context.resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.button_dialog_white)
    btnYes.setTextColor(context.resources.getColor(R.color.dark_grey))

}

public class UserHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

    public var timer: CountDownTimer? = null

}

private class WaitingHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

}
```

}

to cancel all timer :

```
override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    if (adapter != null) {
        adapter!!.cancelAllTimers()
    }
}
```

or cancel timer of particular item of recyclerview

```
for (i in 0 until countDownMap!!.size()) {
                val key = countDownMap!!.keyAt(i)

                if (key.equals((holder as UserHolder).itemView.txtTimer.hashCode())) {
                    val cdt = countDownMap!!.get(key)
                    cdt!!.cancel()
                }
            }
```