# Recycler View update few row every x sec

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-timer

i have view pager . view pager have 3 section/tabs which have same fragments .fragment contains recycleview. 
in recyclerview i have custom layout for row . row contain textview and imagers . for textview its timer which should update every 1 sec . so for now i am using timer with fixe schedule task

```
 Timer timer = new Timer();
  timer.scheduleAtFixedRate( new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {

             textview.settext(updatedvalue);

         }
        }, 0, 1000);
```

i am doing this in bindViewHolder . but now problem is this timer is applicable for only few rows of recycle view . 
 so in this it always call inrespect of that row is visible or not

so say i have total 30 rows and timer is applicable for 1st 4 row (this can be any value depend upon server value) . so how i can do this updating stuff for that row only . which my code is happing for all row so its taking to much memory

Comment: use ... adapter.notifyItemChanged(index);

Comment: every sec adapter.notifyItemChanged is good ?

Comment: i have one adapter for all 3 tab

Comment: do a check if new value available from server... check currecnt_value!=new_value then notify

Comment: no no , value updated locally basically its timer like time reaming value thats y it updating every 1 sec no server call need

Comment: then follow this method... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31059251/how-to-handle-multiple-countdown-timers-in-listview

Comment: i am using recycle view

Answer (score 2):

Once I had solved my problem using this. Hope it will work

```
Handler timerHandler;
timerHandler = new Handler();

Runnable timerRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Here you can update your adapter data
        yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        timerHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000); //run every second
    }
};

timerHandler.postDelayed(timerRunnable, 1000); //Start timer after 1 sec
```